# After install OJS 3.X i cant acess the installation via Localhost

Tags: xampp, ojs

I have a problem, I installed OJS using Xampp, the installation went smoothly, but when accessing localhost/ojs I am receiving the error 500, in the index of my Xampp there is the following sentence:

Something is wrong with the XAMPP installation :-(

I don't know where to start, I've tried renaming index.php to index.txt with no results.

Thank you for your attention.

Tried to rename index.php
Tried reinstall ojs on another xampp database

localhost/phpmyadmin works fine.